# Do hidden views respond to NSNotifications?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsnotifications

I have a two tabs on a `UITabBarController` and I have registered both with `NSNotificationCenter`, my problem is I am not getting notifications on the hidden tab (i.e. its not called `viewDidAppear:` yet). My thinking is that controllers not on screen (i.e. hidden) do not respond to `NSNotifications`. I can do things a different way thats not a problem, but I just want to verify why the hidden tab is not getting the notification in case I am missing something else and it should actually be working ...

## EDIT:

[@Fab1n](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1340499/fab1n) pointed me in the right direction, I had mistakenly used `viewWillDisappear:` to remove the observer, so when the view disappeared is was no longer listening out for notifications. I will move it to `dealloc`.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [notificationCenter removeObserver:self];
}
```

Changed to:

```
- (void)dealloc {
        NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [notificationCenter removeObserver:self];
}
```

Much appreciated.

Comment: When do you register and unregister the for the notifications? Can you show that code?

Comment: I would rephrase the question "Do disappeared view controllers respond to NSNotifications"?

Comment: I was using viewWillAppear to register and viewWillDisapear to remove. This worked fine initially, but now I want to do some updates it means that the controller is not registered when its offscreen (Disappeared)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To stay safe: Register your `NSNotification` in `-init` or (with IB) `-initWithNibName:`**

A controller of a `UITabbarController` is initialized with `init` when you set the `controllers` property of the `UITabbarController`.

`viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` are called each time you make one of the controllers visible by tapping on a tabbar icon.

**Solution:**

1. register your `NSNotification` by overriding `-init` in each of your 'sub'-controllers
2. unregister the notification in `-dealloc` (don't call `[super dealloc]` with ARC!!!)

Now everything works fine!

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know any tab bar element is lazy loaded despite the first one. They get loaded the first time you tap on the representing tab bar item (or by accessing their view property programmatically). Afterwards they can receive any message you want even if you select another tab item.